# Communication between tasks in ECS with App Mesh and Cloudmap

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-app-mesh, aws-cloudmap, aws-networking

My ECS task (that connected to App Mesh with Cloudmap) cannot reach other ECS task (that connected to App Mesh with Cloudmap as well).
`dig +short products.services.local` return nothing.

`curl -v products.services.local:4000/graphql` returns
`Could not resolve host: products.services.local`.

Any help how to debug it will be super helpful.
Btw, running these commands in Cloud9 (within the same VPC) works great. So it's a problem just within ECS or App Mesh with Cloudmap.

There is a private hosted zone in Route53 that has the correct A record (points to the correct task IP), which was created automatically by Cloudmap.

There is a Virtual service and a virtual node in App Mesh for both of the services. Both of their discovery type is AWS Cloud Map and they are pointing to the correct service name and namespace in Cloudmap.

**DNS hostnames configuration is enabled on my VPC configuration**